# Can I write $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$ implies $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{2yx}$ all the time?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Can I write $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$ implies $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{2yx}$  ?

Actually I have been given two differential equations to solve.

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$ , $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{2yx}$

They have done in the following manner.

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2} \implies \frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{2xy}$

Now they have solved this $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{2xy}$.

Solution of this differential equation is the solution of the first one and after that they interchanged $x$ and $y$ to get the solution of second one.

I can not understand how they can do it.

Can anyone please tell me when we can do this ?

Comment: I recommend checking the hypothesis of the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statement).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not convinced, instead of Eq.$(1)$ or Eq.$(2)$ consider the differential equation $(3)$ in which no $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $\frac{dx}{dy}$ appear.
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2} \tag 1$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{2xy} \tag 2$$
$$\boxed{2xy\,dx-(x^2-y^2)dy=0} \tag 3$$
Thanks to the method of integrating factor $(1/y^2)$ the solution is :

$\frac{2x}{y}dx-(\frac{x^2}{y^2}-1)dy=0$

$d\left(\frac{x^2}{y}+y\right)=0$

$\frac{x^2}{y}+y=C$
$$\boxed{x^2+y^2-Cy=0}\tag 4$$
For explicit solutions one can solve Eq.$(4)$ for $x$ or for $y$.

Solving Eq.$(4)$ for $y$ leads to :
$$y=\frac12\left(C\pm\sqrt{C^2-4x^2}\right) \tag 5$$
which is exactly the solution of Eq.$(1)$ that one can check in puting Eq.$(5)$ into Eq.$(1)$.

Solving Eq.$(4)$ for $x$ leads to :
$$x=\pm\sqrt{Cy-y^2} \tag 6$$
which is exactly the solution of Eq.$(2)$ that one can check in puting Eq.$(6)$ into Eq.$(2)$.

Comment: But my question is different. Can you please check my question once again ?@JJacquelin

Comment: Does $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$ imply $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{2yx}$  ?@JJacquelin

Comment: I know how to solve it.

Comment: This is not a question of implying or not. This is a question of manner to write the differential equation $2xy\,dx-(x^2-y^2)dy=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let  $y=f(x)$  represent some function, and assume that it is invertible in a neighbourhood of, and differentiable at, some point  $(x_0,y_0)$  at which  $\frac{dy}{dx}\neq 0$ then the identity holds.


Note that This formula holds in general whenever $ {\displaystyle f}$ is continuous and injective on an interval I, with$ {\displaystyle f}$ being differentiable at ${\displaystyle f^{-1}(a)}{\displaystyle f^{-1}(a)}({\displaystyle \in I})$ and where${\displaystyle f'(f^{-1}(a))\neq 0}$

Comment: Can you please take took at the question. ? I have made some changes.@Amrit Awasthi